# What is the difference between the fill light & blacks and exposure sliders in Lightroom?

Tags: software, lightroom

What is the difference between using Fill Light and Blacks sliders and dealing with the Exposure slider directly in Adobe Photoshop Lightroom?

Answer (score 2):

***Exposure:*** Adjusts the entire image lighter or darker.

***Fill Light:*** Lightens the dark regions to recover detail, but leaves the bright regions alone.

***Blacks:*** Darkens the dark regions.

***Recovery:*** Similar to fill, it attempts to recover detail in the bright regions, leaving the darker regions alone.

Comment: Fill and recovery, if I understand them correctly, are better than simple histogram shifters. They understand image information outside the dynamic range you are currently viewing. Some software calls this "expanded dynamic range" but I think Adobe soft-pedals it. In any case, it can give you an extra edge if you have an exceptionally contrasty image of if you just missed on the exposure.

Comment: Also, if you watch the histogram while using the slider for each control, it highlights the main area of the histogram to be affected (though I don't think it ONLY affects that area).